# windows - pip will not update, install completes successfully but version never changes

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip

I was tired of seeing the warning so figured I'd update pip from 21.0.1 to 21.1.2, however, when using the command D:\Python38\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip, or python -m pip install --upgrade pip, the version never changes to 21.1.2. I have restarted my terminal, I have checked my path, the only thing I can think is that I changed the global.cache dir to my D: drive to conserve space on my windows hog of a machine. Here is a snippet from my terminal of what I have going on.

```
D:\>python -V
Python 3.8.8

D:\>pip -V
pip 21.0.1 from d:\python38\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)

D:\>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-21.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
Installing collected packages: pip
Successfully installed pip-21.1.2
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.0.1; however, version 21.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'D:\Python38\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

D:\>pip -V
pip 21.0.1 from d:\python38\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)

D:\>python -m pip install --upgrade --no-cache pip
Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-21.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.5 MB 939 kB/s
Installing collected packages: pip
Successfully installed pip-21.1.2
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.0.1; however, version 21.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'D:\Python38\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

D:\>pip -V
pip 21.0.1 from d:\python38\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)
```

my pip config debug info:

```
D:\>pip config debug
env_var:
env:
global:
  C:\ProgramData\pip\pip.ini, exists: False
site:
  d:\python38\pip.ini, exists: False
user:
  C:\Users\logan\pip\pip.ini, exists: False
  C:\Users\logan\AppData\Roaming\pip\pip.ini, exists: True
    global.target: D:\Git\pip\site-packages
    global.cache: D:\Git\pip\cache
    global.pip-cache-dir: D:\Git\pip\cache
```

I have scoured the internet for an inkling into why this is happening but I can't seem to find an answer. Thing is, this isn't something that I have to have done, it's just nagging at me that I cant figure it out at this point.

I have read through the pip documentation [config file](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#config-file) and [user guide](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/) and of course I have looked for my answer here before asking my question, I hope someone out there can give me some insight and thank you for your time.

Comment: ```pip -V``` what does this provide now?

Comment: `D:\>pip -V`
`pip 21.0.1 from d:\python38\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)` @Sujay also now added the line in the original post.

Comment: Could you do a `which python` and `which pip`?

Comment: @Maaz I don't follow, is 'which' a command? and if so then no, I can not.

Comment: Ah, no. Sorry. That was for linux. Didn't read the windows tag.